# How to load duplicate /boot

Tags: boot, grub2, ssd

I have an SSD that only seems to boot if /boot and grub are on the hdd. But I also have a duplicate copy of the /boot in a small partition at the front of the SSD. This old laptop may not be able to do it (I've read about similar cases in these forums), but I'd like to see if I can manually get grub to load the duplicate. What other files should I copy to the partition, and what should I change to accomplish this? Should I be making changes to  in grub? Change uuid parameters? Idk what I'm doing (but there's no important data on this laptop, so I'm not too worried). Please help. Running ubuntu solo, btw.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish though? The /boot on the SSD was likely for a separate installation on the SSD.

Comment: I want a faster boot and load times with programs, but programs only load slightly faster and boot takes even longer than before! I've tried a few schemes with gparted, but putting grub2 and /boot on the hard drive while keeping everything else on the ssd is the only way this ssd has been able work. And now ubuntu boots even slower now than before I got the ssd!

Comment: Just to clarify, I want everything in the ssd, solo (that SHOULD be the fastest setup, right?) But when I install 16.04 (auto or with gparted, putting /boot at the front), i don't even get to grub rescue. My laptop (hp dv7-1133cl) tells me there is no bootable disk (i don't even make it to grub rescue). So obviously this ssd is either not compatible with my machine, or this disk isn't initialized yet (how can i even do that without formatting/partitioning?).

Comment: Grub always looks for /boot on the same device by default. Did you run grub-install and grub-mkconfig on the SSD?

Comment: Yes, it gave me an error. In hp forums, I was told that the specific ssd I was looking at would work, but now I've learned that it won't the bios on my old hp dv7-1133cl does not support ahci. I wish I had known about that before I got it. Some other ssds are compatible with ide. So basically, it's a cute little storage device, and not much more.